# MySQL query to get date of record entry or when id assigned

Tags: mysql, date

I've to get users who registered in this year (01-01-2014) but in database user table there isn't any column which preserve Time of entry.

Is there any way/query to get such type of records?

Comment: That would be 2014-01-01 - rookie mistake. And no. If the data isn't stored, you can't retrieve it.

Comment: So there is no time of entry saved? And you want to use that data anyway? That's not going to work...

Comment: You *might* still be able to recover this information from other sources, e.g. logfiles...

Comment: Also, if users are identified by an incrementing synthetic key, you may be able to safely assume that your problem is equivalent to finding all users who have a value for that key greater than that of the first user registered this year... which might somewhat simplify your task.

Comment: @davey Thanks for the reply, but there should be a way (by meta data or any other)? am I right?

Comment: I don't think so, maybe you can get some information from the binary log, if you got that enabled.

Comment: @eggyal the idea you gave, is beneficial in order to find require records. Thanks